# How to insert select to stored procedure with insert?

Tags: sql

I try to create stored procedure, but I had syntax error and I don't know what to change. I want to receive number from the select query to the "@cartypeID" for insert the car type number the the insert code below.

```
create PROCEDURE AddCar (@CarFleetID int,@CarModelName nvarchar(50),@CarNumber nvarchar(50),@CurrentMiles int,@ImageFileName nvarchar(50),@IsOk2Rent bit)
 AS
 IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CarFleet WHERE CarFleetID =@CarFleetID ) = 1
 BEGIN
     RETURN -1
 END ELSE
 BEGIN

   declare @cartypeID int
   @cartypeID= select CarFleet.CarFleetID
  from CarFleet join CarTypes on CarFleet.CarTypeID=CarTypes.CarTypeID join CarModels on CarTypes.CarModelID=CarModels.CarModelID
     where @CarModelName=CarModels.CarModelName

     INSERT INTO CarFleet(CarFleetID,CarTypeID,CarNumber,CurrentMiles,ImageFileName,IsOk2Rent)
VALUES(@CarFleetID, @cartypeID, @CarNumber,@CurrentMiles,@ImageFileName,@IsOk2Rent)

 END
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Also, please add the error message

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
create PROCEDURE AddCar (@CarFleetID int,@CarModelName nvarchar(50),@CarNumber nvarchar(50),@CurrentMiles int,@ImageFileName nvarchar(50),@IsOk2Rent bit)
     AS
     IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CarFleet WHERE CarFleetID =@CarFleetID ) = 1
     BEGIN
         RETURN -1
     END ELSE
     BEGIN


         INSERT INTO CarFleet ( 
             CarFleetID
            ,CarTypeID
            ,CarNumber
            ,CurrentMiles
            ,ImageFileName,IsOk2Rent) 
       select 
              CarFleet.CarFleetID
              ,@cartypeID
              ,@CarNumber
              ,@CurrentMiles
              ,@ImageFileName,@IsOk2Rent
      from CarFleet 
      join CarTypes on CarFleet.CarTypeID=CarTypes.CarTypeID 
      join CarModels on CarTypes.CarModelID=CarModels.CarModelID
      where @CarModelName=CarModels.CarModelName
     END
```

Comment: The @cartypeID isn't exsist in this table i need to get it from anther table

Comment: oops.... select  @CarFleetID ,CarFleet.CarFleetID  ,@CarNumber       ,@CurrentMiles
              ,@ImageFileName,@IsOk2Rent